# Would you ever use "closed-loop" as an adjective without a hyphen?

Tags: hyphenation, compound-adjectives

Is it correct to use "closed-loop" as an adjective without a hyphen?

Example:

> Partners can serve as a recycling hub and sell the products in their
>   stores, telling a closed-loop story.

Our marketing team really, *really* wants to drop the hyphen from "closed-loop". Can I let them?

Answer (score 2):

No, I would not.  That doesn't mean it can't ever be done, but if you omit the hyphen, it introduces uncertainty into the sentence.  A "closed-loop system" is obviously a system that operates as or within a closed-loop environment.  A "closed loop system" could be a "loop system" that is closed as opposed to open.  I don't know whether such a thing as a "loop system" exists, but the possibility exists and that militates against the use of the term "closed-loop" as an adjective without hyphenation.

Answer (score 1):

Of course.  If a retailer in the central business district of Chicago failed, it would be a closed [Loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago_Loop) store, no hyphen.

But if you have a story about a closed loop, that's a closed-loop story.